# WPF update UI control of a window from another window in the same thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

Let's say I define 2 `Window`s named `WindowA` and `WindowB` respectively.

`WindowA` has a `Button` named `btn`.

`WindowB` has a `Label` named `processLbl`.

When user click button in `WindowA`, `WindowB` will be shown and some logic are performed.

```
WindowB windowB;

private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    windowB = new WindowB();
    windowB.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    windowB.Show();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // do something
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        updateLabel(i);
    }

    windowB.Close();
}

private void updateLabel(int value)
{
    windowB.processLbl.Content = value;
}
```

The result is `windowB` is shown but its label's content is not updated.

I guess this is to be expected because both `windowA` and `windowB` are on the same thread.

And because of that, using `Dispatcher.Invoke` is no use.

But is there any way to do that or do I have to show `windowB` on a different thread.

And if I do that, how can I access `windowB`'s label from thread on which `windowA` is running?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread. You should never call it in your UI. Use a DispatcherTimer instead. Or declare btn_Click async and call `await Task.Delay(100)`

Comment: Thanks Clemens. `await Task.Delay(100)` did the job. But if `Thread.Sleep(100)` is the result why windowB's label is not updated then does that mean if I remove that line of code then everything is gonna work as expected?

Comment: @nammae: No, because the loop is still executed on the UI thread. You need to sleep/pause on another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Dispatcher Timer like below,

```
    WindowB window;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window = new WindowB
        {
            Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
        };
        window.Show();  
        timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;          
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Start();

    }
    int tickCount = 1;
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tickCount == 100)
        {
            window.Close();
            timer.Stop();
        }
        updateLabel(tickCount);
        tickCount++;

    }

    private void updateLabel(int value)
    {
        window.lbl.Content = value;
    }
```

As clemens mentioned in the comment, `Thread.Sleep blocks the UI thread`